# Running arbitrary binary program with cluster computers

Tags: networking, memory, disk, process-management, cluster

I have 3 VPS. Let's say master, slave1, slave2.

Their specifications are identic.

- Processor: 1CPU
- Memory: 1GB
- Disk: 10GB
- Network: running on LAN each other

I expect any arbitrary binary program (process) that run on master VPS is seeing as one VPS. So that's mean the workload of master VPS will be shared to its slaves through network.

So what the program will see is, it's running on a computer with specification:

- Processor: 3CPU
- Memory: 3GB
- Disk: 30GB

The question is, any there protocol or service that can combine computing power like that?

To combining memory (RAM) or storage (SSD).
I was thinking to mount ramfs into a mountopoint for every slave. Then using NFS server for every slaves and make it available so that NFS client from master can mount it into local. In master, combining mountpoints into single mountpoint`/mnt/shm_from_slave1` and `/mnt/shm_from_slave2` into single mountpoint `/mnt/shm_combined`.
Then in the combined shared memory in master, I will create swapfile `/mnt/shm_combined/swapfile`. Then configuring the master OS to make swapfile to use frequently. Note that, this is my plan to combine the memory. To combine processor power, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to merge system resources across multiple Linux instances.  This is not totally possible, especially for RAM and CPU.  For disk space NFS and other network shares can help.

Hypothetically it may be possible to spawn processes on another Linux machine so that they consume resources on that other machine and other things like pipes could be simulated through the network.  This model breaks down though because of shared memory.  Shared memory is achieved in linux by processes directly accessing pages of physical RAM that are also mapped into anotherprocess.  Attempting to simulate this would mean some locking mechanism would be needed and that would, most likely, result in such a servere performance hit as to make the solution unviable.

In more general terms what you're asking about is discussed in terms of super computers which can be expressed in very different terms of capability and capacity.

"Capacity" is a measurement the total throughput the whole system can achieve. It's a useful metric if the system is being used to process very many similar jobs, each job can be passed to a single node.  Extending the capacity of the system can be achieved by simply adding more nodes and thus allowing the system to process more jobs in the same space of time.  High capacity systems in VPS services often use tools like Kubernetes to orchestrait a lot of jobs and services over very many nodes.

"Capability" is a measurement, losely, of the size of single job the system can achieve.  This cannot be simply extended by adding new nodes. As you add new nodes to process the same job, so too you add network communication overhead such that attempting to spread the job over more and more nodes would actually make processing slower not faster.

So when you reach the limit of capability of single nodes, the only thing you can do is to try to change the software so that the work is broken into smaller pieces.  By breaking it into smaller pieces you can then distribute those pieces over many nodes and so change a capability problem into a capacity problem.

Just for illustration, this is what [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) is for in the Python programming language.  It takes instructions to perform on a dataset and then automatically breaks up the dataset and instruction so that it can be split over many nodes.

Depending on your needs though, some computational probelms simply cannot be split this way.  And splitting is only a possibilty when you are writing the software yourself.